# Use edit box value for dynamic view panel parameter

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

What I am trying to do is have an edit box, a button and a dynamic view panel on an Xpage and a View in the Notes database.  Then input a document Id in the edit box which, when the button is clicked will use the edit box value as a parameter for filtering in the dynamic view panel.  There seems to be very little on the Internet.  I have tried setting the dynamic view panel's "Keys" property to the value

```
getComponent("inputDocumentID").getValue()
```

And have the button do a full refresh but this does not work.  How can I use the edit box as the dynamic views parameter?  The Notes View selection formula is;

```
SELECT ((Form = "Contract")) & (conContractStatus  = "Cancelled") &     
(initialstagecomplete = "1")
```

Comment: I may have this working by moving the getComponent line of javascript to the "search" property of the dynamic view panel and prefixing it with "return".  But it is not refreshing.  So have to work out that part

Comment: I now have this refreshing when the button is clicked but it is not filtering with the document Id when I first click on the page and instead returning all contracts that meet the view criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this using scoped variables. The idea is to use a mechanism similar to LotusScript's `NotesViewEntryCollection.getEntriesByKey("keyFilter", False)`:
Let's assume you have a Notes view where the first column is sorted by UNID (column formula = `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)`).
Inside your xpage you create your view panel as always. The vp's key property is set to listen to a requestScope variable like this:

```
    <xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel1">
      <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="myView"
            keys="#{javascript:requestScope.keyFilter;}">
        </xp:dominoView>
      </xp:this.data>
      ...
    </xp:viewPanel>
```

Somewhere else on the Xpage you create an editbox and bind it to your requestScope var like this:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{requestScope.keyFilter}">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onkeyup" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewPanel1">
  </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

As you see every input is immediately stored in my scope variable, and every keyup event performs a partial refresh on the view panel thus refining the key filter as I type.

*Remark:*
There's a caveat in case your view panel comes with a pager: if you start filtering while your vp isn't showing page #5 applying a key filter could render an empty view. Reason is that the view still is showing page #5 but there just isn't enough data left  to show on 5 pages.

Solution again is quite simple: add a few lines of server side script to your edit box's `onkeyup` event thus resetting the view to show page #1:

```
getComponent("viewPanel1").gotoFirstPage();
```

Comment: @LotharMuellar Thanks.  I have this working the way I want it except one problem.  If the button is clicked with the edit box empty an alert is shown asking user for a value - but the message box displays twice.  Why is this?  I have the following code in the dynamic view panels "search" property. var strInputID = getComponent("inputContractID").getValue()
if (strInputID === "")
{strInputID = "Enter Contract ID";
var scriptCode = "alert('You must enter a Contract ID')"
view.postScript(scriptCode); }
return strInputID

Comment: Hard to tell just from the code fragment. But for one: code validation in my opinion should always occur at the source, or at the trigger. The search property should only be used for calculating or consuming the result. - In your case if the search is triggered through a button click then you should put the validation there; or you also could use the editbox's validation property.